# Word usage: Date before

Tags: phrase-requests, time

How one can say that a date must happen before other date, for intance:

> The X starting date should be prior to the Y starting date.

Is this sentence idiomatic or there is another way of stating that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say that one should **precede** the other.

Comment: On reflection, I like this answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Your example makes perfect sense to me; I can see no need to vary it.

Answer (score 3):

There's certainly nothing wrong with using words like *prior* and *precede* in OP's context, but they're not exactly everyday language for the masses. In common parlance, people are much more likely to say something like...

> *X should **be earlier than** Y*

...or...

> *X must **come before** Y*

Answer (score 0):

In the world of project management, you would say

> The Y starting date *depends upon* the X starting date.

See this [glossary of Project Management terms](http://www.pmgloss.com/about/). (It does not define "depends upon" but rather uses it axiomatically.)

*Depends upon* would be stronger than the modal ("should be") that the OP employed. If you used the sentence above, you would be saying that the starting date of X *must* (not should) be prior to the starting date of Y.